# How can e-commerce sites remember my cart list even after I close browser and revisit?

Tags: django, e-commerce

I want to know how e-commerce sites(e.g `Amazon`) remember my shopping cart list even though I didn't login at all before.

It still showing my cart list even I close all browser and revisit it.

Do they make session not to expire even after closing its browser?

I'd like to implement this in `Django` and need your advices.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way: With Cookies that don't expire on session end, but after a given time (for example one day or one month)

Try to open the URL with a different browser...

Answer (score 0):

This is done by storing data in the session and keeping the session active for a period of time.

Django includes a very handy session framework that makes doing that rather easy - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/